# Castle resolving in deep hierarchy

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a problem with configuring our castle windsor ioc container to do what I want.

I have the following structure:

```
SessionInfo : ISessionInfo

ConnectionInfo(ISessionInfo sessionInfo);
Repository(IConnectionInfo connectionInfo);
```

All these classes are instantiated by castle. This is the default case. Now I need to modify the `SessionInfo` from the outside. To accomplish this I implemented an `StaticSessionInfo`. Now I have exactly one case, where the `ConnectionInfo` object should not be a `SessionInfo` object but a `StaticSessionInfo` object.

Unfortunately I don't have access to the code that calls the Resolve parts. I just can configure the castle windsor container and at the end get the `Repository`.

I think I need the ability to do some register like the following but I cant get it working:

```
windsorContainer
 .Register(Component.For<IRepository>()
                    .ImplementedBy<Repository>()
                    .Named("DynamicRepository")
                    .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent<ISessionInfo, IStaticSessionInfo>()));
```

The part that is not working is the `DependsOn` part.
Am I on the right path or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: Don't you need to specify the implementation type, not the interface, as the second type parameter to `OnComponent`?

Comment: @PhilDegenhardt you are right, this works, you can submit your comment as a answer and I will mark it as the solution. But I will not use such a way because I think its not a good solution in general, see my answer for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the implementation type, not the interface, as the second type parameter to OnComponent.

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately a colleague of mine has a way better Idea to solve the problem and I implemented that way. While doing that I got the opinion that my solution I posted here is not good in general.

**Why?**

How did I get the idea to do it this way? I saw the implementation of the IConnectionInfo class that was used for my special case. I saw that it has a dependency to the ISessionInfo interface. If I dont had the possibility to see the implementation, I had never seen that dependecy. Because of this I think the solution I wanted to implement first is not only not good but a bad one.

Comment: Good to hear. It might be helpful to other users if you could show the alternative approach.

Comment: My approach is specific to our application but maybe it helps someone else too. We have a SOA and for every service call castle resolves the repository and other components. When you call an service, you can specify the session. So instead of doing my work in the current serivce, I just invoke an other service with the desired session. This way I all I need out of the box.